# Jackson's 2.2.0 release throwing INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES on Android

Tags: android, jackson

I just pulled down the latest Jackson 2.2.0 libraries, and got the following error when building in Eclipse:

```
[2013-04-30 23:46:34 - app] Android Launch!
[2013-04-30 23:46:34 - app] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-30 23:46:34 - app] Performing com.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-04-30 23:46:34 - app] Uploading app.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-04-30 23:46:35 - app] Installing app.apk...
[2013-04-30 23:46:38 - app] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
[2013-04-30 23:46:38 - app] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-04-30 23:46:38 - app] Launch canceled!
[2013-04-30 23:48:15 - app] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: NOTICE
Origin 1: /workspace/app/libs/jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar
Origin 2: /workspace/app/libs/jackson-core-2.2.0.jar
```

Cleaning and rebuilding did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/214) was already raised and a fix is available in the current source. You can also wait for Jackson 2.2.1.

Comment: Jackson 2.2.1 was released 03-May-2013, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an error with duplicate files in the Jackson libraries.  Removing these files from the core library fixed it for me.

The following commands will eliminate the duplicate files.  (And potentially wipe out any maven/repository info that relies on META-INF files.  Not a problem for me, but might be for someone else).

```
zip -d jackson-core-2.2.0.jar NOTICE
zip -d jackson-core-2.2.0.jar LICENSE
zip -d jackson-core-2.2.0.jar META-INF*
```